# How to update property of javascript/typescript function defined using Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I'm trying to do something like this below

```js
function foo() {
    return true;
}

Object.defineProperty(
    foo,
    'propertyOnFoo',
    { value: 'valueOnFoo', writable: true, configurable: true }
)

const propertyDescriptorOfFoo = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(foo, 'propertyOnFoo');
// update the property value without using Object.defineProperty to replace it with new object.
```

I'm trying to do this in TypeScript, but accessing the property using signature `foo['propertyOnFoo']` will fail at the compile time. Is there any feasible way to accomplish this on a function?

Comment: Use a type assertion to tell the TypeScript compiler that `foo` is not just a `Function` instance, but also has a `propertyOnFoo` property.

Answer (score -1):

Did you consider
`Object.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, 'propertyOnFoo)`